# ISAPI Url Rewrite - from http to https

Tags: url-rewriting, isapi

I have to url redirect a link which is an HTTP link, but it should redirect to an HTTPS form. How do I do that using ISAPI rewrites?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using IIS6 your best bet is to use http://iirf.codeplex.com/ IIRF.